# C++ access global integer from class header file

Tags: c++, class, variables, integer, header-files

I have a header file that declares a class, and I want this class to access an integer that has been declared in the main cpp C++ file (i.e. another file than the class' one). I have been searching on Google and found nothing relevant. How can I do this?

Comment: declare the integer in a header file as `extern`

Answer (score 1):

To share a global variable among source files, use the `extern` keyword.

main.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

int global_var=0;

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

extern int global_var;

void foo();

#endif
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

int foo()
{
    global_var=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the integer in main.cpp into a function, make it static there, have the function return a reference to it and put the function into a header file of its own which the class header file (or implementation file, if appropriate) includes.

integer.h:

```
#ifndef INTEGER_H // use some better, longer name here
#define INTEGER_H

int &Integer();

#endif
```

integer.cpp:

```
#include "integer.h"

int &Integer()
{
  static int i = 0;
  return i;
}
```

Access the integer like this:

```
int x = Integer(); // copy

Integer() = 123; // assign
```